# Show that for any set A and a relation $R$: $R^{0}=Id_A$

Tags: set-theory, induction, relations, function-and-relation-composition

We define the power of a relation in the following way:

$R^{1}=R$

$R^{2}=R \circ R$

$R^{3}=R \circ R^{2}$

and we want that for every $n,m: R^{n} \circ R^{m}=R^{n+m} $.

More formally we can also define it by induction in the following way:

($R^{0}=Id_A$)

$R^{1}=R$

$R^{n+1}=R^{n}\circ R$

Given that definition I would like to prove that for every set $A$, a relation $R$ and a natural number $n$:
$R^{0}\circ R^{n}=R^n$ implies $R^{0}=Id_A$.

Comment: What’s stopping you? Seriously, what ideas do you have? What have you tried? How far has it gotten you? What do you think has caused it to fall short?